# How to define axiom of a line as two points in Coq

Tags: geometry, coq, formal-methods

I am trying to find an example *axiom* in [Coq](https://github.com/GeoCoq/GeoCoq/blob/master/Axioms/euclidean_axioms.v) of something like the line axiom in geometry: If given two points, there exist a line between those two points. I would like to see how this could be defined in Coq. Inherently choosing this simple line axiom to see how something very primitive is defined, because I'm having a hard time defining it outside natural language.

Specifically, I have seen these two axioms and would like to know how in Coq to define both:

> 1. Any two distinct points always determine a line
> 2. Any two distinct points of a line determine this line uniquely

It almost seems like you can merge them into one definition, so I would like to see syntactically and semantically how to write this in Coq.

I don't know how to write Coq really, just looking to see how they do it. But if I were to try it seems like this:

```
Axiom line : forall ptA:Point ptB:Point, line ptA ptB.
```

But that needs a Line and a Point object.

```
Axiom line : forall ptA ptB, line ptA ptB.
Definition Line ptA ptB -> (...) No idea.
Definition Point ...
```

Comment: There is an (old perhaps) axiomatisation of euclidian geometry in https://github.com/coq-contribs/euclidean-geometry . It shows _one_ way to do it, there are other ways too. It is quite large, probably way more than what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility.  The `exists!` connective means unique existence.

```
Axiom point : Type.
Axiom line  : Type.
Axiom lies_in : point -> line -> Prop.
Axiom ax : forall (p1 p2 : point), p1 <> p2 ->
           exists! l : line, lies_in p1 l /\ lies_in p2 l.
```

Comment: Wondering if you can natural-language-ize `Axiom lies_in : point -> line -> Prop.`, to me it says "if a point then a line is a proposition", but I don't really understand what that means or how I'd figure that out on my own. I get the gist of the rest of the other axioms though.

Comment: `Prop` is the type of propositions. An element of `point -> line -> Prop` is a two-argument function that maps a `point` and a `line` to a proposition. In other words, it is a relation between points and lines. The intended reading in this case is that `lies_in p l` asserts that the point `p` lies in the line `l`.

Comment: For better readability, I would advise to use `Parameter` for introducing `point`, `line`, and `lies_in` and use `Axiom` only at the time of stating a proposition, here `ax`.