# What <> is in Coq

Tags: coq

It's difficult to search for but wondering what `<>` means as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937970/how-to-define-axiom-of-a-line-as-two-points-in-coq/54938069#54938069):

```
Axiom point : Type.
Axiom line  : Type.
Axiom lies_in : point -> line -> Prop.
Axiom ax : forall (p1 p2 : point), p1 <> p2 ->
           exists! l : line, lies_in p1 l /\ lies_in p2 l.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x <> y` form is a notation for `not (x = y)` -- that is, it asserts that it is not the case that `x` and `y` are equal. Negation is defined by setting `not P := P -> False`. In other words, by showing `P`, we obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

`x <> y` is a notation for `~(x = y)` (which itself is a notation for `(x = y) -> False`). It's possible to search for notations with the `Locate` vernacular command, which is used like `Locate "<>".` and gives output like

```
Notation
"x <> y  :> T" := not (eq x y) : type_scope
(default interpretation)
"x <> y" := not (eq x y) : type_scope
(default interpretation)
```