# How to implement `forall` (mathematics) in a procedural or OO language

Tags: javascript, ruby, proof, formal-methods, forall

I am trying to understand how to implement `forall` in a procedural or OO language like Ruby or JavaScript. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937970/how-to-define-axiom-of-a-line-as-two-points-in-coq/54938069#54938069) (this is Coq):

```
Axiom point : Type.
Axiom line  : Type.
Axiom lies_in : point -> line -> Prop.
Axiom ax : forall (p1 p2 : point), p1 <> p2 ->
           exists! l : line, lies_in p1 l /\ lies_in p2 l.
```

My attempt at doing this is just defining a class such as this (call `MainAxiom == ax`).

```
class MainAxiom
  attr :p1
  attr :p2

  def initialize
    raise 'Invalid' if @p1 == @p2
    l = Line.new
    check_lies_in(l, @p1)
    check_lies_in(l, @p2)
  end

  def check_lies_in(line, point)
    ...
  end
end
```

This has all kinds of mistakes. It essentially says "for every axiom that you create with points p1 and p2, it must satisfy the properties of being on a line, etc.." This doesn't quite do what I want it to do. I want it to accomplish the mathematical goal of defining an actual axiom.

Wondering how to accomplish this in a language like Ruby or JavaScript, something as close to as possible if it's not directly possible. Even if it's just a DSL or an object defining some data, that would be helpful to know how to do as an alternative.

The first part that gets me is that, the `attr :p1` and attr definitions *seem to apply to every instance*. That is, **it seems to say something about *forall***, but I can't pinpoint it.

Maybe something more like this is closer:

```
class MainAxiom
  # forall p1 and p2
  attr :p1 # forall p1
  attr :p2 # forall p2
  attr :line (p1, p2) -> Line.new(p1, p2)

  check_lies_in :p1, :line
  check_lies_in :p2, :line
end
```

I just want to have anything even halfway close to a `forall` definition in a procedural/OO language.

Comment: Where do you get the `Line` class from ?

Comment: I'm just writing pseudocode.

Comment: It would be nice to see _how do you plan to use it_. Now I can tell that plain instantiation of this line in the initializer is kinda proof of its existence.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm allowed to reason in Smalltalk, where blocks are objects of the class `BlockClosure`, I would assume that you represent the *property* you want to quantify as a block `p`.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the property depends on one single parameter `x`. Then `p(x)` would correspond to the Smalltalk expression

```
p value: x
```

which evaluates the block `p` using the argument `x`.

In this way, you could implement the Smalltalk method `forAll:` in the class `BlockClosure` as:

```
forAll: aCollection
  aCollection do: [:x | (self value: x) ifFalse: [^false]].
  ^true
```

which checks that the property `p` represented by the receiver block evaluates to `true` *for all* the elements in `aCollection` (your universe).

If your universe doesn't change (the usual case in the context of a problem), and what changes is the property, you could define the class `Universe`, which would hold the collection of elements in its instance variable `contents`. Then, you could implement in `Universe`

```
forAll: aProperty
  ^aProperty forAll: contents
```

where the inner `forAll:` message is the one implemented in `BlockClosure`.