# How forall is implemented in Coq

Tags: coq

In trying to understand how to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939289/how-to-implement-forall-mathematics-in-a-procedural-or-oo-language) `forall` in JS or Ruby, I would be interested to know how it's actually implemented in Coq. Maybe that will help shed some light. I don't seem to find the definition by searching around on Google. Mainly just looking for a link in the source code somewhere.

Comment: To clarify: are you implementing a programming language in Ruby/JS and want to know how to implement `forall` for that language; or are you asking how to express `forall`-like construct in JS/Ruby itself?

Comment: Either/or, I am just playing around with how to define it with a DSL in ruby, but I don't care how it is defined as long as it's in a procedural/oo language.

Answer (score 3):

Coq's `forall` is a [dependent product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000001-QINU%60%22'%7F_type) and cannot be directly encoded in a dynamically typed languages like Javascript because they simply lack the concept of static type.

It serves the purpose of giving a static type to some nonsensical from the point of view of some languages, functions. Consider we have an infinite collection of types `T1`, `T2`...

Then this function cannot be assigned a (nontrivial) type by conventional methods:

```
function foo(n) {
  return eval("new T" + n + "()");
}
```

However, we can give it dependent (`forall`) type, using a helper function

```
function H(n) {
  return eval("T" + n);
}
```

The type of `foo` then will be `forall n:Number, H(n)` (given Number, returns an object of type `H(n)`, ie `Tn`).

Unfortunately, there is no way for us to convey this information to the JS interpreter to statically enforce this contract. However, we can check it at runtime!

Lets start by making a small type checking framework.

```
function type_number(x) {
  if (typeof x == "number") return x;
  throw new Error("not a number");
}

function type_function(x) {
  if (typeof x == "function") return x;
  throw new Error("not a function");
}

function type_instance(clss) {
  return function (x) {
    if (x instanceof clss) return x;
    throw new Error("not an instance of " + clss);
  };
}
```

Now we can implement a non-dependent function type

```
function type_arrow(arg, ret) {
    return function(f) {
        f = type_function(f);
        return function(x) {
            return ret(f(arg(x)));
        };
    };
}
```

Here `arg` must be a type checker for the argument, and `ret` must be a type checker for the return value. For example:

```
// declare a function from numbers to numbers
var fn1 = type_arrow(type_number, type_number)((x) => x * x);
fn1(10); // works
fn1("asdsa"); // fails

// bad declaration, but, unfortunately, JS cannot possibly catch it at "compilation" time
var fn2 = type_arrow(type_number, type_number)((x) => "Hello!");
fn2(10); // fails, return value is not a number
```

Now to the fun part:

```
function type_forall(arg, ret) {
    return function(f) {
        f = type_function(f);
        return function(x) {
            var y = f(arg(x));
            return ret(x)(y);
        };
    };
}
```

Notice how `ret` is now a curried function of two arguments. Given my first example, we can now give a type to `foo`:

```
function T1(){}
function T2(){}
function T3(){}
function T4(){}
function T5(){}
// ...etc

function foo(n) {
    return eval("new T" + n + "()");
}

function H(n) {
    return eval("T" + n);
}

function type_H(n) {
    return type_instance(H(n));
}

var typed_foo = type_forall(type_number, type_H)(foo);
typed_foo(2); // successfully invokes and returns a T2 instance
```

Note that we cannot give a non-trivial type to `foo` with `type_arrow` - we need `n` to properly typecheck the return value.

But this is nowhere near the power Coq gives us, simply because it does not catch any errors at compile time. If you really want these guarantees, you must materialize language constructs as first class objects and perform your own type checking. One article I could recommend is http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/10/simpler-easier-in-recent-paper-simply.html